# Google chrome frame overlay works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome-frame

I have a page that prompts for a *Google Chrome Frame* installation if the user uses an outdated browser.

It works great if the user chooses to install the plugin. But, if he/she choose not to install it and closed the layer; It's impossible to open the layer again using the same button. (Basically it works only once.)

**Is there any way I can force Google Chrome Frame to open every time I click on install?**
  (I've tried forcing a cookie, but doesn't seem to work.)

### update [#1]:

Test page [here](http://dev.pierre-cholhot.com/gcf.html).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="dngcf">Prompt</a>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                if( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9 ){
                    if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf('chromeframe') < 0 ){
                        $('.dngcf').bind('click', function(){
                            //document.cookie = 'disableGCFCheck=0;path=/;';
                            CFInstall.check({
                                url: 'http://www.google.com/chromeframe/eula.html?user=true',
                                mode: "overlay",
                                destination: "http://mywebsite.com"
                            });
                        });
                    }else{
                        alert('GCF is already installed');
                    }
                }else{
                    alert('You need IE 6, 7 or 8 in order to see the "bug".');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### update [#2]:

This seem to be a **session-related problem**.
When i restart the browser, the link works again once. But doesn't however when i only refresh the page.

### [conclusion]

**This behavior is by design**. It allows an admin to `check()` for GCF on every single page, without annoying the user with a prompt every time.

> ### The accepted answer allows you to circumvent this behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right about the cookie, but it annoyingly also sets a private variable when it shows the popup, so without hacking the cfinstall script we're looking at overriding existing methods.

This is the best I can get.  There's a problem where pressing "cancel" and then "close" means that the popup is still on the 2nd page when you pop it back up again, but you can install from there so I don't think it's that big an issue.  (The pedant in me doesn't like it though!)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="dngcf">Prompt</a>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9){
                    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("chromeframe") < 0){
                        $(".dngcf").on("click", function(){
                            if ($(".chromeFrameOverlayContent").length > 0) {
                                $(".chromeFrameOverlayContent, .chromeFrameOverlayUnderlay").show();
                            } else {
                                CFInstall.check({
                                    url: "http://www.google.com/chromeframe/eula.html?user=true",
                                    mode: "overlay",
                                    destination: "http://mywebsite.com"
                                });
                                $("#chromeFrameCloseButton").off("click").on("click", function() {
                                    $(".chromeFrameOverlayContent, .chromeFrameOverlayUnderlay").css({ display: "none" });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('GCF is already installed');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('You need IE 6, 7 or 8 in order to see the "bug".');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 The pedant in me doesn't like it either :) but it does the trick. Cheers!

Comment: Heh - you're welcome mate.  If I come up with any solution to that then I'll update the answer.